# How to cache data during the first epoch correctly (Tensorflow, dataset)?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to used the `cache` transformation for a `dataset`. Here is my current code (simplified):

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=1)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size=5000, count=1))
dataset = dataset.map(_parser_a, num_parallel_calls=12)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(
    20, 
    padded_shapes=padded_shapes,
    padding_values=padding_values
)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=1)
dataset = dataset.cache()
```

After the first epoch, I received the following error message:

> The calling iterator did not fully read the dataset we were attempting
>   to cache. In order to avoid unexpected truncation of the sequence, the
>   current [partially cached] sequence will be dropped. This can occur if
>   you have a sequence similar to `dataset.cache().take(k).repeat()`.
>   Instead, swap the order (i.e. `dataset.take(k).cache().repeat()`)

Then, the code proceeded and still read data from the hard drive instead of the cache. So, where should I place `dataset.cache()` to avoid the error?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you consume the data from `dataset`? In particular, how do you determine how many steps to take? If you read `dataset` to the end (i.e. when a related iterator raises `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError`) then it should successfully cache.

Comment: Thanks, @mrry. I will try to use `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` to determine the end of my `dataset`. Currently, I calculate the number of batches in one epoch by `num_batches_per_epochs=math.ceil(num_Training_examples / batch_size)`. Once the batch count reach `num_batches_per_epochs`, I consider one epoch is complete and starting the next epoch (starting by `sess.run(iterator.initializer)`).

Comment: After using `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` to determine the end of `dataset`, no error message anymore (also works fine when resuming the training after a few epochs). Thanks again, @mrry.

Comment: If we use `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` to determine the end of a `dataset`, the `count` of the  `repeat` transformation should be 1, otherwise it will never throw `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The implementation of the [`Dataset.cache()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache) transformation is fairly simple: it builds up a list of the elements that pass through it as you iterate over **completely** it the first time, and it returns elements from that list on subsequent attempts to iterate over it. If the first pass only performs a **partial** pass over the data then the list is incomplete, and TensorFlow doesn't try to use the cached data, because it doesn't know whether the remaining elements will be needed, and in general it might need to reprocess all the preceding elements to compute the remaining elements.

By modifying your program to consume the entire dataset, and iterate over it until `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` is raised, the cache will have a complete list of the elements in the dataset, and it will be used on all subsequent iterations.

Comment: Hi @mrry. If my `map()` involves random behavior (like random crop and random rotation), where should I put `cache()` relative to `map()`? My guess is put `cache()` before because you don't want to train on the same crops of images for following epochs.

Comment: That's right: if you put `cache()` *after* the random `map()` then it will cache the first set of random decisions. Putting the `cache()` *before* the random `map()` should work as expected. (Note that this means you might want to split your `map()` into two parts, with the deterministic part before `cache()` and the random part after `cache()`.)

Comment: what about the shuffle method ? If the cache method is placed afterwards then it will render the shuffling useless and always return the data in the same order. If it is so, i think this should be stated in the documentation more clearly

Comment: @SamueleCornell Yes, it is now stated in the documentation. Check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache). It says "cache will produce exactly the same elements during each iteration through the dataset. If you wish to randomize the iteration order, make sure to call shuffle **after** calling cache."

Comment: Awesome ! The tf.data.Dataset documentation is now much much better. I remember at the time it was rather scarce ( due to the fact the API was kinda new).