# Do I cache dataset before dataset.repeat() dataset.batch() and dataset.prefetch() or after?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pipeline, tensorflow-datasets

I am building a data pipeline using Dataset API in order to train on multiple GPUs. The dataset consists of large number of png images with multi-hot labels. Do I cache before batching or before / after repeating, prefetching? The objective is to minimize IO and memory use while maximizing training speed.

```
def input_fn():
    ...
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size = batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.cache()

    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=None)

    return dataset
```

Comment: The [performance considerations](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets#performance_considerations) can be very helpful when deciding order of execution. Generally, you would want to use cache before you use repeat. Here is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50536314/10111931) on how cache works and a [github discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15694#issuecomment-354377649) on the same.