# Warning: The calling iterator did not fully read the dataset being cached. In order to avoid unexpected truncation of the dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

This occurred while I was using `tf.data.Dataset`:

> The calling iterator did not fully read the dataset being cached. In order to avoid unexpected truncation of the dataset, the partially cached contents of the dataset will be discarded. This can happen if you have an input pipeline similar to `dataset.cache().take(k).repeat()`. You should use `dataset.take(k).cache().repeat()` instead.

According to other questions, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519343/how-to-cache-data-during-the-first-epoch-correctly-tensorflow-dataset), it has something to do with where `cache()` is in the sequence of methods, but I can't understand what to do concretely.

Here's how to reproduce the warning:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

ds = tfds.load('iris', split='train')

ds = ds.take(100)

for elem in ds:
    pass
```

Seems like no matter what I do, and no matter where I use `cache()`, the warning pops up.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your code on `Google colab`, it ran successfully without giving any warning, I'm using `Tensorflow 2.3`.

However, you can follow this general method while using `cache`.

If the dataset is small enough to fit in memory, you can significantly speed
up training by using the dataset’s `cache()` method to cache its content to
`RAM`. You should generally do this after loading and preprocessing the
data, but before `shuffling`, `repeating`, `batching`, and `prefetching`. This way,
each instance will only be read and preprocessed once (instead of once per epoch)

Comment: This warning shows up in TF 2.9 but I did not get it in TF 2.4. So it's something that they added. I do not use `take(k)` or `repeat()` so I don't know what it's talking about. And batching happens after cache. And prefetching is last. And I'm only caching the validation data but the warning appears when I call `model.fit()` but before the first epoch is completed. Tbh I think it's a nonsense warning that's only relevant for some specific use case an engineer imagined without testing whether it would trigger under other circumstances.

Comment: when you call `.fit()` there's an inherent call to `take()` every time a batch is processed. Also, if you define `n_epochs`, then `repeat()` is called automatically every time an epoch ends until total number of epochs is over (or early stop is called)