# `tf.data`: Are `cache` and `repeat` compatible, and, if so, in what order should they be applied to a `tf.data.Dataset`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, tensorflow-datasets

In order to ensure samples are repeated indefinitely, the [`repeat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat) method with `None` or `-1` as argument for `count` can be applied to a `tf.data.Dataset`. However, due to a [time-consuming](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#caching) sample generation process, it is also necessary to use the `cache` method. Are these two methods compatible, and, if so, in what order should they be applied to a `tf.data.Dataset`? Neither [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) nor [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance) address this specific issue.

The reason for the need of repeating samples indefinitely is due to `tf.distribute.DistributedDataset`’s requirement to specify `steps_per_epoch` in `tf.keras.Model.fit`. Additionally, instead of automatically re-using the dataset after every epoch, the dataset gets exhausted and must therefore contain a number of batches equal to (at least) the number of steps per epochs multiplied by the number of epochs.

Note: Due to some constraints resulting from a remote computing environment, TensorFlow-GPU version 2.4.1 is being used.

**TL;DR**: Are `tf.data.Dataset.repeat` and `tf.data.Dataset.cache` compatible, and, if so, in what order should they be applied to a `tf.data.Dataset`?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the *.index cache-file only gets created after one entire iteration over the dataset. Thus, the following code can be used to check **when** this file gets created.

```
import tensorflow as tf, os

n_originals = 100
cache_dir = "./cache_dir/"
cache_file = "cache_file"
os.mkdir(cache_dir)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(n_originals).cache(os.path.join(cache_dir, cache_file)).repeat()
for i, sample in enumerate(ds):
    if cache_file+".index" in os.listdir(cache_dir):
        print(i)
        print("Cache files have been created, meaning that they are now being used to iterate over.")
        break
```

Output:

```
100
Cache files have been created, meaning that they are now being used to iterate over.
```

This means that the cache files were created after one iteration of the dataset, and is unaffected by the `repeat` method, which then repeats elements from cache.

Edit: Also, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64755186/15589661