# Confused about usage of tf.data.Dataset pipeline transformations

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I'm new to the `tf.data` API, and I'm trying to learn how it works and how to use it properly by building an image classification model using images stored on disk.

I've been following the tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#using_tfdata_for_finer_control) (from Tensorflow.org). I get the gist of it, and the loading/processing seems to be working fine. The problem starts from the *Configure dataset for performance*. I have a function defined as follows:

```
def config_ds(ds):
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=ds.cardinality().numpy())
    ds = ds.map(process_img,num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
#     ds = ds.map(augment_img,num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    ds = ds.cache()
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    return ds
```

(Note the mapping of the `augment` function which is commented out - I'm not using augmentation yet, but I'd like to in future so I've left it in here). This seems to work, insofar as I can generate and plot/inspect a batch of images, but it's quite slow and always outputs the following message:

```
The calling iterator did not fully read the dataset being cached. In order to avoid
unexpected truncation of the dataset, the partially cached contents of the dataset  
will be discarded. This can happen if you have an input pipeline similar to 
`dataset.cache().take(k).repeat()`. You should use `dataset.take(k).cache().repeat()` 
instead.
```

Does this mean that the data is being read in full from disk, and thereby not taking advantage of the performance optimisation functions? I've been reading about the `shuffle`, `cache`, `prefetch`, and `repeat` functions, but I don't understand them well enough yet to grasp the warning message. Other questions here ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519343/how-to-cache-data-during-the-first-epoch-correctly-tensorflow-dataset)) made me think the problem was related to the batch size not evenly dividing the data, but I've tried change the batch size and the warning persists. I've also tried to change the order of the functions as the warning suggests (assuming that the `take()` is represented by `batch()` in my example, is that correct?), to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

How large is your dataset? My first guess is that all those images are not fitting into RAM memory at some point.

I don't know if you're aware, but you're trying to fit everything processed after map into RAM memory on your first epoch. This is the default behaviour when you didn't provide any file_path in the `cache()` call. If you did, then it'd be saved into a file in your disk (that would persist across different runs)